# Windows 7 generic drivers run over my specific mouse drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, mouse, hid

I have recently purchased a gaming mouse from a company named SteelSeries, I am running Windows 7 (32 bit) and they do provide drivers for my system. I have installed everything as instructed (and as I have done many times before) but it seems that windows decides to use the generic mouse drivers (`mouclass.sys` and `mouhid.sys`) instead of the ones I provided, I have tried updating the drivers manually but Windows claims they are up to date, but still the gaming mouse is recognized only as a `HID-compliant` device and not by it's full name and not using any of the supplied drivers.

I have tried temporarily removing the Windows drivers but still they are copied again from some Windows backup I guess and used.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to uninstall drivers completely and re-install them again.

Comment: perhaps you need to run a program first. I had problems with mouse scrolling before on Windows 7. It turned out that I had to run the Synaptics program first to be able to scroll.

Comment: I have tried re-installing the drivers several times but still the same effect occurs every time, I have tried running the added software but still nothing changed. I have contacted the company's support staff but still no response.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an automatic driver update, Windows will use the latest ones available.

It sounds like the drivers are older than Windows' generic ones. As a result, Windows is selecting the newer generic ones.

What you want to do is to perform a manual update.

1. Click *Update Drivers* on the mouse
2. Instead of automatic, select *browse my computer*
3. Select *let me pick*
4. Click *have disk*
5. Select the folder where the drivers are stored
6. Select your device
7. Click `[OK]` / `[Finish]` / `[Accept]` / etc.

Note: if you enter the folder at step three instead of selecting *let me pick* Windows will see your drivers, but notice the timestamp is old and just use the ones.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Tried this and it told me it could not find any drivers in that folder, though I am sure these are the drivers for this mouse (confirmed with their support staff), although I am running 32 bit I have tried disabling driver signing verification just to rule that one out but still, I'll try using an older version or something

Comment: There will be one or more `.inf` files in the driver directory or one of its subdirectories. If the one in the top directory does not work (it may even be just an `autorun.inf` file instead of a driver information file), then try specifying one of the subdirectories instead.